# SQL - Query Join result is empty even though there are data in one of the tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables named `tNetworkSocket` and `tPatchpanelPorts` which I use to filter data.
I have data when I execute `SELECT * FROM tPatchpanelPorts` but, when `SELECT * FROM tNetworkSocket` there are no data. This is correct.
If I execute

```
SELECT Distinct HostID, HostName, HostTypeID, DomainName 
FROM tHosts, tDomains, tPatchpanelPorts, tNetworkSocketPort 
WHERE tHosts.DomainID=tDomains.DomainID 
AND ( tPatchpanelPorts.ConnectedHostID = tHosts.HostID OR tNetworkSocketPort.ConnectedHostID = tHosts.HostID) And AccountID=1
```

I get no data, but if i remove `tNetworkSocketPort` from the query it looks like:

```
SELECT Distinct HostID, HostName, HostTypeID, DomainName 
FROM tHosts, tDomains, tPatchpanelPorts 
WHERE tHosts.DomainID=tDomains.DomainID 
AND ( tPatchpanelPorts.ConnectedHostID = tHosts.HostID) And AccountID=1
```

I get data.

What am I missing

Comment: If you do an `INNER JOIN` to a table with no data, it will effectively filter out all of the results.

Comment: Switch to modern, explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read, and easier to convert to outer join (if needed.)

Comment: BTW, are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Use left outer join and implement what u are looking for

Comment: @jarlh thanks for suggestion and I am sorry for that.

Comment: `inner` join REQUIRES there be data on both sides of the join. If your one table is empty, then you are getting EXACTLY what you asked for: no data, because the one table's got no data.

Comment: You should avoid using a comma separated list of tables. That syntax has been replaced by the ANSI-92 style join syntax for almost 30 years now!! https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: To understand why your joins are behaving the way they are you should take a look at this article. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Not replaced. Current SQL standard (SQL-2015) has both versions.

Comment: True @jarlh, the ANSI-89 style joins have not been replaced but the legacy format is just awful. It is highly prone to error and a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-Writing query with Explicit JOIN Syntax and for table I have used LEFT JOIN, this may help you

```
SELECT Distinct HostID, HostName, HostTypeID, DomainName 
FROM tHosts
INNER JOIN tDomains ON tHosts.DomainID=tDomains.DomainID 
INNER JOIN tPatchpanelPorts ON tPatchpanelPorts.ConnectedHostID = tHosts.HostID
LEFT JOIN tNetworkSocketPort ON tNetworkSocketPort.ConnectedHostID = tHosts.HostID
WHERE AccountID=1
```

Comment: I have tPatchpanelPorts as a LEFT JOIN because in the first query either this one OR tNetworkSocketPort has to match the HostID. So you would be excluding records that did not have a matching HostID in tPatchpanelPorts even though they do in tNetworkSocketPort. Maybe the OP can clarify

Comment: You can remove the join on tNetworkSocketPort altogether, because it has no effect on the query. Using an inner join on tPatchpanelPorts and then applying `DISTINCT` is a clumsy way of emulating an `IN` or `EXISTS` clause, but doing the same with an outer join simply does nothing (except for giving the DBMS unnecessary work to do). In spite of this answer having been accepted, I find it unlikely that the query does what the OP wants it to do, because of tNetworkSocketPort being in the original query, but not really being in this one.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner well, Thanks for such nice explanation, I appreciate your efforts, but may be OP got what he looking for, that's why op accepted this as ans.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this with a few joins:

```
SELECT Distinct HostID, HostName, HostTypeID, DomainName 
FROM tHosts 
INNER JOIN tDomains
ON tHosts.DomainID=tDomains.DomainID
LEFT JOIN tPatchpanelPorts
ON tPatchpanelPorts.ConnectedHostID = tHosts.HostID
LEFT JOIN tNetworkSocketPort 
ON tNetworkSocketPort.ConnectedHostID = tHosts.HostID 
WHERE AccountID=1
```

Answer (score 1):

The out-dated comma-separated joins you are using are very hard to read. Your query translates to:

```
SELECT Distinct HostID, HostName, HostTypeID, DomainName 
FROM tPatchpanelPorts pp
CROSS JOIN tNetworkSocketPort nsp
JOIN tHosts h ON h.HostID IN (pp.ConnectedHostID, nsp.ConnectedHostID)
JOIN tDomains d on d.DomainID = h.DomainID 
WHERE AccountID = 1;
```

You cross join tPatchpanelPorts and tNetworkSocketPort to get all possible combinations. As one of the tables is empty, there are zero possible combinations. Then you join the other tables to this empty result set, which remains empty of course.

Moreover `DISTINCT` is very often a sign for a poorly written query. And really, you are joining four tables, when you only want data from two of them. The other tables belong in the `WHERE` clause.

I assume you want this:

```
SELECT h.HostID, h.HostName, h.HostTypeID, d.DomainName 
FROM tHosts h 
JOIN tDomains d ON d.DomainID = h.DomainID 
WHERE AccountID = 1
AND
( 
  h.HostID IN (SELECT ConnectedHostID FROM tPatchpanelPorts)
  OR
  h.HostID IN (SELECT ConnectedHostID FROM tNetworkSocketPort)
);
```

(I suppose that AccountID resides in either tHosts or tDomains. You should use a qualifier to make this clear.)